# Does iOS Twilio allow to access CMSampleBufferRef while Video streaming is going on?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio-api, avcapturesession, twilio-video

Is it possible to get the frames from the Camera feed while Video streaming is happening through Twilio SDK.

I want to pass the camera feed (Local camera) to ML model while it's being transmitted to live streaming through twilio webRTC GO.

Is it possible to do that ?

I would like to get the same sample buffer data that we get in following method through twilio SDK

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
```